# AppEngine social application

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I started developing my application in AppEngine Java, however I noticed that Facebook has officially discontinued the support for the Java API and the third party API was last updated a year ago.

Does anybody use Java + Social plugins? How has it been going so far? Should I switch to Python, I'd not want to since, I'm not very great with Python and have written significant amounts of code in Java already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) on Google App Engine for a year now. It does almost all I need it to do (get friends list, get photos, upload photos). It uses the old REST api but [I have not seen a deprecation date](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap) for the methods I use.
I also use Apache HTTP Client to do some Graph API calls not available in the REST api (deleting a photo for example).

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use python, try a look to vikuit social. It runs over Google Appengine , it's open source ( GNU3) and perhaps it's a good base to your development.